# Cant read a simple listBox Text/Number

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't read a simple value from listBox (Text/Number) on the main thread from one line (value like *989238923*, *121293*).

I tried following, nor of them works, the result is always empty.

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    string Test = Convert.ToString(listBox1.Text);
    string Test1 = Convert.ToString(listBox5.GetItemText(listBox1.Text));
});
```

Working Stuff...

```
              int index = listBox1.FindString(Test);
              listBox1.SetSelected(index, true);
```

Comment: `listBox1.Text` is the text of the _list box_, not of the _item in the list box_. What framework are we talking about? wpf, winforms? If there are multiple items in the listbox, the text of which do you want? the selected? the first? the last?

Comment: I don't see the benefit in calling `Convert.ToString` to convert a string (`listBox1.Text`) to a string.

Comment: @RenéVogt Its a winform, the listbox have only one number inside, so the first one.

Comment: Also for the reference: [`ListBox`'s `Text` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.text?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.Text);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) returns (or searches) text that is currently selected in `ListBox`, so make sure that your text was selected, before getting its value. There is no need to convert `string` property again to `string`.

Comment: @SeM Ye, Thank you, i forgot to select the text inside the listbox....

Comment: @SeM But is there no other way to get the Value (its just one not multiple lines) without select?

Comment: @Kabundscha sure, if you sure that there is only one element and it's primitive type (string, int...), you can for example write `listBox1.Items[0].ToString();`

Comment: @SeM Short and Simple, good Help, thanks :)